# How to display code blocks with word wrap and line number with jekyll markdown on github-pages

Tags: css, jekyll

I am using github pages to host my blog. It uses GitHub Flaword Markdown. Here is part of `_config.yml`:

```
markdown: kramdown
# Use Github Flavored Markdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

My articles often contain long  lines of code, and I would like to display it with word wrap(so it can be all seen without scrolling) and with line numbers(that allow to distinguish new line from word warp).

I found, that I can enable word wrap, if I use this css property for `<pre>` tag: `white-space: pre-wrap`. But how can I display line numbers? I am looking for solution that will allow me to continue using github-pages built-in jekyll, that generates blog pages for me automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but wrapping long lines in code highlight **doesn't work** with line numbers.

```
{% highlight ruby linenos %}
def dosomething
  delegate :some, :thing, :with, :unicorns, :and, :shrimps => :yolo, :someother key => true, :maybeonemore => true
end
{% endhighlight %}
```

See [Jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#line-numbers).

And CSS wrapping for long lines :

```
.highlight pre{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

**But finally this problem cannot be resolved with just jekyll or kramdown/rouge config.**

This, because, line numbers are stacked in a `<td>` near the code `<td>`.

If you can wrap code, line numbers are not wrapping accordingly, and it ends up like this :

```
  def foo
1    wrapped very long line
2  wrapped very long line continues here
3
  end
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, but not with `white-space: pre-wrap` :( Is there any way to have both line number and word wrap in jekyll?

Comment: So maybe, you can approve my answer. For me the white-space problem deserve another question.

Comment: I will approve it after some time, waiting for somebody to give us a complete solution, both with numbers and word wrap.

Comment: `{% highlight lineos %}` together with `wite-space: pre-wrap` and long code lines works incorrectly :(

Answer (score -1):

Code::Blocks version 20.03 for wrap code line settings<Editor<General Settings<Other Editor Settings<Word Wrap